# THE process cannot access the file because it is used by another process in C#

Tags: c#

> The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process

I'm getting this error while moving or deleting but work fine in case of copying

```
private void frombtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
         f1 = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        textBox2.Text = f1;

    }

    private void tobtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog();
         f2 = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;
        textBox1.Text = f2;
    }
    string f2;
    string f1;
    private void movebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // List<string> mf = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            string tempsource = "";
            string tempsources;
            string tempdests;
            string tempdest = "";
            int i = 0;
            String[] moving = new String[500];
         //   Stack<string> fsource = new Stack<string>();
           // Stack<string> fdest = new Stack<string>();

            string f16;
            DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(f1);
            foreach (FileInfo files in dr.GetFiles())
            {

                string f = files.FullName;
                bool c = Chek(f);


                if (c == true)
                {

                    tempsource = f;
                    f16 = files.Name;
                    tempdest = f2 + "\\" + f16;
                  //  files.MoveTo(tempdest);

                   // System.IO.File.Move(tempsource, tempdest);
                   // tempdest = "";
                    tempsource = "";
                    count++;

                    moving[i++] = f;

                }
                else
                {

                }


            }


           foreach (string s in moving)
            {

                tempsources = s;
                tempdests = tempdest;
                System.IO.File.Move(tempsources,tempdests);


            }



                MessageBox.Show("Moved Successfully ");
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(er.Message);

        }
    }


    public bool Chek(string p)
    {

        bool res = false;
        Bitmap img;
        if (p == null)
            return false;
        img = new Bitmap(p);
        for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
            {

                Color c1 = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                if ((c1.R > c1.B) || (c1.G > c1.B))
                {

                    res = false;



                }
                else
                {

                    res = true;
                    break;
                }


            }
            if (res == true)
            {

                break;

            }
        }

        if (res)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you use File.Move method, just curious...

Comment: Chek should Dispose the bitmap

Comment: Please help me soon I'm getting this error for last 2 days but find no suitable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `Chek` method opens the file and loads it into a bitmap. The file will remain open until the bitmap is disposed, but you never dispose it.

You can use a `using` block to conveniently and safely dispose the bitmap:

```
public bool Chek(string p) {
  if (p != null) {
    using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(p)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++) {
          Color c1 = img.GetPixel(i, j);
          if (c1.R <= c1.B && c1.G <= c1.B) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You open the file in `Chek` on this line

```
    img = new Bitmap(p);
```

You don't wrap this in a using statement or dispose the bitmap. So you haven't closed the file.

If you check using SysInternals Handle.exe I'd reckon it was your own program that has the file open and is blocking the delete.

Note that move is the same as Copy then Delete.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states one or more of the files you're trying to move/delete are open in other programs/used by other processes. This could be in the case of a Word document open in word, or a game files being used by a game. This doesn't happen when you copy a file, because the original file is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Windows programming! Deleting a file will often fail (moves are similar to deletes), if anything else is accessing a file then you probably can't delete it, a big culprit of this is anti virus scanners. The only real solution is to put retries around moves and deletes with a short sleep after each failure. Obviously you should limit the number of retries in case the file really is locked.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when one process uses a file it locks the file so that others can only read from it. When you copy files, you just read them. When you move/delete, you need exclusive rights on the file. That is why copy works even if the file is in use by other processes, but not move/delete.

If the files are used only by your app that means that somewhere in code you open files but never close them. That might well happen in the 'Chek' function where you create a Bitmap object out of a file. You should dispose the objects that use files after they are not needed. Even if the GC should do that, it might not kick in in time before your move/delete code runs so the files are still in use.

Another solution (not recommended though) is to manually call collect on GC before the move/delete code execution.